# Star Background

Tags: rendering

When I render in User Ortho mode, I do not see the starfield background i have set up for the World Settings.  Only when I am in User Persp mode, and render, do I see my star background.

[image: User Ortho view]

In other words, in order to view the starfield background, I must render the image using the User Perspective view.  But this distorts the look of my object (b/c of the perspective angles). I want to view/render my object in it's orthographic profiles, and view it from different angles, WITH the starfield background.

Comment: you could maybe place an image plane behind your scene's objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand it, HDRI image background mapping has something to do with the angle of camera's field of view because the background is infinitely far away. Orthographic cameras have no field of view - all projected rays are straight - so they show a single pixel of the HDRI background that they happen to be pointing at on the infinitely big sphere that the image is mapped to. So an HDRI background cannot be shown through an orthographic camera. You can however have any other type of background. You can use an emission shader and map an HDRI image on a sphere around your scene that has a certain size(as opposed to infinitely big sphere in the case of the HDRI image mapped on Blender's 'World') and it will be displayed. Or you could have a simple plane behind your objects.